# Show tooltip on hover over text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I want to create extension that allows to show custom message when I hover over a text.

E.g. "test-text" should give tooltip "OK" instead of current "ITrackin..."

I tried to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-quickinfo-tooltips?view=vs-2019
but people are stating that it is not working and it's quite long way of doing this.

I cannot find any more docs on this. I know how to display it in on-click window/get currently selected text.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncQuickInfo).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work on one machine, but fails on the second. (No error, visual studio 2019 on both machines)

Comment: If it can work on one machine A but no another B. Maybe you can try [Export all vs settings](https://community.submain.com/blogs/howto/archive/2009/05/30/how-to-backup-and-restore-visual-studio-settings.aspx) in A, and use machine B to import it. Then both VS2019 have same settings. After that, make sure both projects are C#.

Comment: Both machines had the same settings. Solved by reinstalling VS2019.

Comment: Solved? So it seems this issue go away, maybe you can share the details and final solution as answer to help other members :)

Comment: Yes, I'll share it later today. As soon as I have time to describe it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample send by Lance Li-MSFT was really helpful, but in order to get this working I had to spend some time.

Important steps:

- Import LineAsyncQuickInfoSourceProvider.cs and LineAsyncQuickInfoSource.cs
- Add reference to System.ComponentModel.Composition by add reference dialog (right click on the project name)
- Get missing references by installing them using NuGet Package Manager
- To initialize MEF components, you’ll need to add a new Asset to source.extension.vsixmanifest.

```
<Assets>
    ...
    <Asset Type = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" />
</Assets>
```

**LineAsyncQuickInfoSourceProvider.cs**

It's just used to display quick info/tooltip.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace JSONExtension
{
    [Export(typeof(IAsyncQuickInfoSourceProvider))]
    [Name("Line Async Quick Info Provider")]
    [ContentType("any")]
    [Order]
    internal sealed class LineAsyncQuickInfoSourceProvider : IAsyncQuickInfoSourceProvider
    {
        public IAsyncQuickInfoSource TryCreateQuickInfoSource(ITextBuffer textBuffer) //creates instance of LineAsyncQuickInfoSource for displaying Quick Info
        {  
            return textBuffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty(() => new LineAsyncQuickInfoSource(textBuffer)); //this ensures only one instance per textbuffer is created
        }
    }
}
```

**LineAsyncQuickInfoSource.cs**

Here you can customize what you want to display.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.StandardClassification;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Adornments;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JSONExtension
{
    internal sealed class LineAsyncQuickInfoSource : IAsyncQuickInfoSource
    {
        private ITextBuffer _textBuffer;

        public LineAsyncQuickInfoSource(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        {
            _textBuffer = textBuffer;
        }

        // This is called on a background thread.
        public Task<QuickInfoItem> GetQuickInfoItemAsync(IAsyncQuickInfoSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var triggerPoint = session.GetTriggerPoint(_textBuffer.CurrentSnapshot);

            if (triggerPoint != null)
            {
                var line = triggerPoint.Value.GetContainingLine();
                var lineSpan = _textBuffer.CurrentSnapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(line.Extent, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);
                var text = triggerPoint.Value.GetContainingLine().GetText(); //get whole line of current cursor pos

                ContainerElement dataElm = new ContainerElement(
                ContainerElementStyle.Stacked,
                new ClassifiedTextElement(
                    new ClassifiedTextRun(PredefinedClassificationTypeNames.Keyword, "MESSAGE TO EDIT: " + text.ToString())
                ));
                return Task.FromResult(new QuickInfoItem(lineSpan, dataElm)); //add custom text from above to Quick Info
            }

            return Task.FromResult<QuickInfoItem>(null); //do not add anything to Quick Info
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // This provider does not perform any cleanup.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works to show custom information when hovering over code, but Visual Studio will still append its standard information such as "class System.String" to the bottom of the QuickInfo box. Do you know if there is a way to suppress this standard Info?

Comment: Should be possible, but I didn't do anything related for ~3y so I'm not sure how. The docs about it were mostly missing and this solution was mostly trial and error.