# How to write an extension that displays different text than the underlying file? (like the parameter names)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I want to write an extension for Visual Studio that replaces the "var" keyword with the explicit type, but only visually and not in the code itself.

After some MSDN and web resarches, I tried using the VisualBuffer (the projection buffer) of the ITextViewModel, but it also changes the code in the file.

Here for example I tried it the other way around by replacing "int" with "var"

```
[Export(typeof(ITextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
internal class TestViewCreationListener : ITextViewCreationListener
{
    private ITextBuffer _buffer;

    public void TextViewCreated(ITextView textView)
    {
        ITextViewModel textVM = textView.TextViewModel;
        _buffer = textVM.VisualBuffer;

        string text = _buffer.CurrentSnapshot.GetText();
        int index = text.IndexOf("int ");
        while (index > 0)
        {
            _buffer.Replace(new Span(index, 3), "var");
            index = text.IndexOf("int ", index + 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `but it also changes code in the file`, so you don't want to change the var to int or what, are you referring to quick info like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453937/show-tooltip-on-hover-over-text)?

Comment: right, I am working in a team and don't want to change the code of the guys who love the "var". But, I hate it and want to see the explicit type without using the mouse tooltip

Comment: I understand that you want to get the explicit type, but which way do you like if you don't want the quick info format? Since you're not changing the var in code file, I'm not sure which way you want to get the explicit type, hover over it and get the type?

Comment: No, I was thinking like of a converter in WPF or so, that replaces what you see but not the model behind it. But, maybe this is not possible. I know that there are also projection buffers, but as far as I understood, they are used to show text on another place (like an outlining window)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found a solution by myself. Using an IntraTextAdornmentTagger did it :)

Comment: Hi GeluX, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)